# hide-show table rows with a given class name with pure javascript

Tags: javascript

Looking for pure javascript solutions only please.

i have this table of tasks that were carried out. Now I have a set of link that refer to actions taken. When an action is clicked, only rows that have this action should be shown:

```
     1  Moved                    James
     2. Installed                James         
     3. Delivered                Eric
```

Each of the rows have a class that refers to the action taken such as

```
     <tr class="action Moved">....</tr>
     <tr class="action Installed">...</tr>
```

I added the "action" class to each and every row so I would hide them all at once then show the requested one. But it is not going smooth. Here is what I attempted:

```
       var showList = document.querySelectorAll("Moved"); //show only rows that are related to Moved action

      var nodeList = document.querySelectorAll("action"); //all action rows
      var len=nodeList.length;
    if(len==0) {return false;}
      for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
          nodeList[i].className='c_hidden';
        }

  //show back. replace the c_hidden class with c_show class

       var reg= new RegExp('(^| )c_hidden($| )','g');

   var len=nodeList.length;
    if(len==0) {return false;}
      for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
          showList[i].className = showList[i].className.replace(reg,'c_show');
        }
```

When I first click say the Moved button, it filters all Moved rows successfully but then, it cant unhide all or other groups. Hope I am making sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `nodeList[i].className='c_hidden';` replaces all classes from the element and consequently `action`class too, this makes the `document.querySelectorAll("action");` get no matching elements to restore with `c_show` when this code is executed again.

Another thing to mention is that the `/(^| )c_hidden($| )/g` regular expression removes white space separators between classes and it could be problematic later,
`/(^)?c_hidden($)?/g` could be better.

Comment: Thanks Leon. I was thinking this is like addClass of Jquery. Lemme see. Thanks a bunch for both hints. WIll check you in a minute.